# Approaching $\infty$ in $\mathbb R^n ; n=2$ or higher.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

say I have a double limit in the sense of having a function from $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ in which there are two variables approaching infinity:.

$$\lim_{n,m \to \infty} f(m,n) $$

I am thinking specifically to the expression :

$$\lim_{n,m \to \infty}  \left(1-\frac{c}{m}\right)^n $$

for $c$ a Real constant.

First of all, how does one approach infinity in $\mathbb R^n ; n \geq2 $? Do we work with 1-point compactifications and then we demand that the values of each of $m,n$ be eventually in a neighborhood of $\infty$  (in the 1-pt compactification, the neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the complements of compact sets)?

Secondly, for the limit, say $L$ to exist, do we require that the above expression $f(m,n)$ approach $L$ in a $\delta -\epsilon$ sense, no matter how $m,n$ approach infinity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The formulations is for any $\epsilon>0$ there is an $M>0$ such that $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}>M$ implies $|F(m,n)-L|<\epsilon$. This will guarantee that $f(m,n)$ gets arbitrarily close to $L$ regardless of how $(m,n)$ approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Very interesting way of approaching the problem.

Comment: @bd1251252 Yes, not only that, it is the standard way of approaching the problem.

Comment: I'm working my way through a book about discrete math and proofs right now, sorry I didn't know that :(

Comment: No, need to frown. You've just learned something new. :)

Comment: I see, so this means , given $ \epsilon >0$ that there is M so that outside of any ball of radius M, $|f(m,n)-L | < \epsilon $? Does this generalize to finite dimensions so that, say $ sqrt(m_1^2+m_2^2+...+m_n^2) >M$ then $|f(m_1,..,m_n)-L| < \epsilon$? Also, is this equivalent to saying that $m_1, m_2,..,m_n$ should take values that are eventually in every neighborhood of $\infty$ , meaning they should take values in the complement of every compact set, where a neighborhood of $\infty$ is as in the 1-pt compactification which is homeo. to $S^n$?

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: @Tim Rac :Sorry, I usually wait for a full day to read and rethink; will give the points after that.